# PHP PDO execution in a function

Tags: php, pdo

I've created this class:

```
class  data
{
public function del($cat, $id)
{
    global $dbh;

    $del = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM :cat WHERE id = :id");
    $del->bindParam(":cat",$cat);
    $del->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $del->execute();
}
}
```

And I'm running into an issue with binding the

```
:cat
```

variable to the statement, if I don't use bindParam for

```
:cat
```

and just tell it which table I want it to delete it from, for example:

```
$del = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = :id");
```

It works fine.

I know it has to be some stupid error, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure using a parameter as table name is possible?

Comment: You can't bind table or column __names__, only __values__ for columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you're trying to do [is simply not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Using table as parameter name is not possible with PDO.

[Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

[php.net post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304)